# rpm package failure, package still installed

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm working on building an rpm pacakge however I noticed this scenario. When my rpm scripts fails, the rpm is still considered installed in my system. I was thinking of adding in the clean up logic where if an error is detected in my rpm scripts, I can call an 'rpm -e' in my code and uninstall the script. However it seems a bit kludgy. Is there a cleaner way of making sure the rpm is uninstalled if the script fails?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us an example in your spec file? I assume this is in the %post section of your spec file? Why not just put it in the %pre section, and then if the script fails it exits?

Comment: I do it in the %post because I need to access certain files that is only available after the package is installed. If something in the %post step fails, the script exits and prints out an error but the rpm is still considered installed when I do a "rpm -qa | grep 'packagename'". I was thinking of adding logic to the script to manually uninstall the current package if the script fails. (Also in the %post) section. Would this be a good way of doing it?

Comment: As Aaron's answer says that won't work, you should look at migrating any code to the %post section as opposed to having it run a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Either `%pre` fails and it is not installed, or you're installed. You cannot call `rpm -e` because the RPM DB is locked for your transaction.

If something fails, I recommend you write out to `STDERR` and make sure that you [re]run `chkconfig` to turn your service off so it won't try to launch next time they reboot.